# attachment not sent with email from ipad

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6

I have an iPad that has a routine to create a pdf and send as an attachment to an email. It all seems to work with the email composer opening showing the pdf document attached. However when tested on an iPad, when the email is received there is no attachment. Any ideas?

```
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"pdffile.pdf"];
    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Many thanks

Detail:

The pdf file is created and called pdffile.pdf. The following is the full email routine:

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;
    mailComposer  = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailComposer setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [mailComposer setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"i-observe Lesson Observation for: %s", "date"]];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"i-observe Lesson Observation for: %s", "name"] isHTML:NO];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"pdffile.pdf"];
    NSMutableData *data=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"pdffile.pdf"];
    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Can we see 1) The initialization of mailCompose 2) The initialization of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Method:

```
 if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){      

        MFMailComposeViewController *mail=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate=self;
        [mail setSubject:@"Email with attached pdf"];   
        NSString *newFilePath = @"get path where the pdf reside";

        NSData * pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:newFilePath];
    [mail addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"yourpdfname.pdf"];
        NSString * body = @"";
        [mail setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
        [mail release];         
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Message cannot be sent");
    }
```

Comment: I am not able to connect to an iPad for a few days. As soon as I do I will let you know.

Comment: I appreciate your help with this. It was not the problem however. It was that stringByAppendingFormat:@"pdffile.pdf"]; should have been stringByAppendingFormat:@"/pdffile.pdf"]; Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The next solutions is based assuming that the pdf file is in your main bundle:

```
 NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *myFile = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"RealNameofFile" ofType: @"pdf"];
        NSData *pdfD = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
        [mailViewController addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"Nametodisplayattached.pdf"];
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the file has the same name as the table cell

Comment: This is more of a "comment" than an answer. First of all, an answer has already been accepted, and unless you think you have a better answer, you shouldn't post one. As you can see, the accepted answer has a full explanation and code of how to fix the problem. This just has a suggestion, and there isn't much reasoning, etc, behind it. I know you can't post comments yet on this site, but if you have something which should be in a comment, isn't an answer, and isn't extremely important, just don't post anything.